# How to Generate a PDF in a Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, pdf

I have been struggling few days with PDF generation. I belive HTML to PDF might be the best way for my application. I have tried several methods in C#, JS, and some online APIs to no luck.

**This is the template I'm trying to acheive**

. [image: [here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/707481146610679868/952008859633975396/unknown.png?width=477&height=676)]

Could someone help me out, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a webpage with this layout
2. Populate the data in the webpage
3. Get the HTML markup of the webpage
4. Use a library like HiQPDF, to pass the HTML Data. This should generate the PDF for you

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does it support the Arabic language?

Comment: Yup, any language. I use this for clients in the UAE all the time :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I ll try it and let you know

Comment: No problem, here's a sample
https://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to remove the watermark at the top of each page in the pdf?

Comment: @AhmadAlmosallam I think you might have to purchase a license for HiQPdf. If you don't want to purchase one, you can try another library and follow the same method.

Answer (score 0):

From C# run a command line like:

```
cpdf -add-text "300 SAR" -topleft 600 -font "Helvetica" -font-size 14 template.pdf -o step1.pdf
```

See:
https://community.coherentpdf.com/